# How to fix port error when dockerizing .Net API

Tags: c#, .net, docker, api, port

I am trying to dockerize my .Net API and I cannot seem to get access to it after I create a container with it. I attempt to send a request using postman but I get a "Socket Hang Up" error. I believe this has to do with the ports I am using although I am not sure how to fix it. Below is all the information I could gather.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY WebAPI.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI.csproj"

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /publish

RUN dotnet build

FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

**Commands:**

```
docker build -t webapi:latest .    
docker run -p 5000:5000 webapi:latest
```

**Postman Proxy:**

```
127.0.0.1:5000
```

**P.S** I have tried changing the ports in multiple ways, changing proxy settings for postman and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to `http://+:80/` in the aspnet image, which makes your application listen on port 80.

So your run command should map port 80 like this

```
docker run -p 5000:80 webapi:latest
```

Then your API will be available on http://localhost:5000/

Note that Swagger is only available when your application runs in Development mode and the Docker environment is not considered development. So by default, Swagger won't be available.

Update: Since I don't have your program source code, I've created the following Dockerfile that runs `dotnet new` to create a fresh template webapi project.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new webapi -n WebAPI -o .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish .
CMD ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

I then run the following commands to build, run and test the container

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm -d -p 5000:80 test
curl http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast
```

and I get the expected result from the API.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply, this question has gone unanswered in so many forums. I already attempted to use docker run with 5000:80 and I still get the same error

Comment: I've updated my answer with a full example of creating an image and running it. Hope that helps.